# I need to implement this C# method in javascript. Need help please

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was using this method in code behind in c#.net. I would pass the date fetched from the database into this method's parameter and then get date written in informal format. Now what is happening is that I have to implement the same thing in my jquery code and

I need to use this function there. In my JavaScript file I am getting the date as a string. Now the problem is that I have no clue how to convert theat string into a Date! Then hpw should I use that date and pass it on to this function? Then do conversions for example this .....(int)s.TotalSeconds;

Give me some ideas how I can implement what I want. I am new to JQuery and stuff.

```
 static string GetInformalDate(DateTime d)
        {
            // 1.
            // Get time span elapsed since the date.
            TimeSpan s = DateTime.Now.Subtract(d);

            // 2.
            // Get total number of days elapsed.
            int dayDiff = (int)s.TotalDays;

            // 3.
            // Get total number of seconds elapsed.
            int secDiff = (int)s.TotalSeconds;

            // 4.
            // Don't allow out of range values.
            if (dayDiff < 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // 5.
            // Handle same-day times.
            if (dayDiff == 0)
            {
                // A.
                // Less than one minute ago.
                if (secDiff < 60)
                {
                    return "Just Now";
                }
                // B.
                // Less than 2 minutes ago.
                if (secDiff < 120)
                {
                    return "1 minute ago";
                }
                // C.
                // Less than one hour ago.
                if (secDiff < 3600)
                {
                    return string.Format("{0} minutes ago",
                        Math.Floor((double)secDiff / 60));
                }
                // D.
                // Less than 2 hours ago.
                if (secDiff < 7200)
                {
                    return "1 hour ago";
                }
                // E.
                // Less than one day ago.
                if (secDiff < 86400)
                {
                    return string.Format("{0} hours ago",
                        Math.Floor((double)secDiff / 3600));
                }
            }
            // 6.
            // Handle previous days, months and years.
            if (dayDiff == 1)
            {
                return "Yesterday";
            }
            if (dayDiff < 7)
            {
                return string.Format("{0} days ago",
                dayDiff);
            }
            if (dayDiff < 31)
            {
                return string.Format("{0} week(s) ago",
                Math.Ceiling((double)dayDiff / 7));
            }
            if (dayDiff < 365)
            {
                return string.Format("{0} month(s) ago", Math.Ceiling((double)dayDiff / 31));
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Format("{0} year(s) ago", Math.Ceiling((double)dayDiff / 365));
            }

            return null;
        }
```

@ IAbstractDownvoteFactory :: I am in that chat room. can you please come if your still here..waiting..need help bad :(

Is there anyone else who can help me out please??

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you might want to look at this plugin instead: http://timeago.yarp.com/ - Should be easy to adapt to match the output of the above code.

Comment: `(int)s.TotalSeconds` equivalent to javascript: `+(s.TotalSeconds)`

Comment: What's "unformal"? Do you mean "informal"?

Comment: @Jack: What about this TimeSpan class  TimeSpan s = DateTime.Now.Subtract(d);
 ?? How do I use this in my js file?

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-prettydate/

Comment: @Michael: Is that script like free to use?

Answer (score 1):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EWFpV/1/)

```
function GetUnformalDate(d) {
    // 1.
    // Get time span elapsed since the date.
    var s = new Date().getTime() - d.getTime();

    // 2.
    // Get total number of days elapsed.
    var dayDiff = (s / 86400000) | 0;

    // 3.
    // Get total number of seconds elapsed.
    var secDiff = s / (1000);

    // 4.
    // Don't allow out of range values.
    if (dayDiff < 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // 5.
    // Handle same-day times.
    if (dayDiff == 0) {
        // A.
        // Less than one minute ago.
        if (secDiff < 60) {
            return "Just Now";
        }
        // B.
        // Less than 2 minutes ago.
        if (secDiff < 120) {
            return "1 minute ago";
        }
        // C.
        // Less than one hour ago.
        if (secDiff < 3600) {
            return Math.floor(secDiff / 60) + " minutes ago";
        }
        // D.
        // Less than 2 hours ago.
        if (secDiff < 7200) {
            return "1 hour ago";
        }
        // E.
        // Less than one day ago.
        if (secDiff < 86400) {
            return Math.floor(secDiff / 3600) + " hours ago";
        }
    }
    // 6.
    // Handle previous days, months and years.
    if (dayDiff == 1) {
        return "Yesterday";
    }
    if (dayDiff < 7) {
        return dayDiff + " days ago";
    }
    if (dayDiff < 31) {
        return Math.ceil(dayDiff / 7) + " week(s) ago";
    }
    if (dayDiff < 365) {
        return Math.ceil(dayDiff / 31) + " month(s) ago";
    }
    else {
        return Math.ceil(dayDiff / 365) + " year(s) ago";
    }

    return null;
}
```

As fpr your date string, we have to parse that:

```
var digits = "29-07-2011 12:51:33".match(/\d+/g);
var date = new Date(digits[2], digits[1], digits[0], digits[3], digits[4], digits[5])
```

Comment: it looks like this 29-07-2011 12:51:33

Comment: On my page its giving this error : - d.getTime is not a function . What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you change the date to you string?

Comment: I modified it a bit like this.............    function GetPrettyDate(t) {

    var date = new Date((t || "").replace(/-/g, "/").replace(/[TZ]/g, " ")),
  diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
  day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);


    // 1.

Comment: Now I dont think its returning correct date..like I passed the date as "2011-09-06 12:43:00.720" and it returned "0 days ago". What's wrong now? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is the date being fetched from the database "2011-07-29 12:11:16.050" When I passed this as parameter to your method ..its returning 77 years ago. Is my date format incorrect in th etable or what? Please reply. Thanks..

Comment: In the database the dates are all being stored like this only..for example  ........  2011-07-29 12:11:16.050, 
2011-07-29 12:51:33.677, 
2011-09-02 12:20:55.993, 
2011-09-02 12:21:39.740, 
2011-09-06 12:43:00.720,

Comment: How do I modify your method to work with the date formats that I have in the database?

Comment: new Date(digits[0], digits[1], digits[2], digits[3], digits[4], digits[5])

Comment: ok I made the change you said. Now when I passed this particular date it returned NULL.. "2011-09-02 12:20:55.993" Why so? Please help me out.

Comment: well, that date hasn't happened yet

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3430/discussion-between-iabstractdownvotefactory-and-infinity)